# How to find max value in a set of lists in prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

My predicate is `lll(C,R)` Where `C` is a country and `R` is a continent.

Example of data that is needed for the predicate:

```
% ------------------
% country(N,C,Ar,Pop), a country N with
% capital C, area Ar and population Pop
% ------------------
country( andorra , 'Andorra la Vella' ,     450 ,    72766 ) .
country( angola  , 'Luanda'           , 1246700 , 10342899 ) .

% ------------------
% continent(N,Pop), N is a continent with population Pop.
% ------------------
continent('Europe',9562488).

% ------------------
% geo_sea(N,C,P), the sea N is in country C in province P
% ------------------
geo_sea( 'Andaman Sea' , india , 'Andaman and Nicobar Is.' ) .

% ------------------
% encompasses(C,R,Fr), country C is encompassed
% by region R to fraction Fr (percent)
%-------------------
encompasses( austria             , 'Europe'  ,100 ) .
encompasses( afghanistan         , 'Asia'    ,100 ) .
encompasses( antigua_and_barbuda , 'America' ,100 ) .
encompasses( albania             , 'Europe'  ,100 ) .
```

I want the biggest landlocked country so

```
lll(C,R) :-
  country(C,_,_,_),
  continent(R,_),
  not(geo_sea(_,C,_)),
  encompasses(C,R,100),
  setof( Circumf, circumference(Circumf,C), Cs ),
  max_list(Cs,CirMax),
  circumference(CirMax,C)
  .
```

This is what I came up with

When i use this `lll(C,'Europe')` all landlocked countries get outputted instead.

I want the country with this biggest circumference to be outputted.
Issue right now is that the list only contains 1 element so when max is used on a list with 1 element it gets outputted.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to identify the largest circumference. With that all countries that are that large (and that are in that continent) can be determined.

```
lll(Country, Continent) :-
   setof(NegCircumf,
      C^Circumf^
         (  country_continent_circumference(C, Continent, Circumf),
            NegCircumf is -Circumf
         ),
      [NegCircumf|_]),
   Circumf is -NegCircumf,
   country_continent_circumference(Country, Continent, Circumf).
```

`setof/3`'s third argument is ascending, so we need to negate the values.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Your data was in any case incomplete, so it was not clear how to define this relation.

Comment: It **could** be that `encompasses/3` might be used transitively. This was the case in the original Chat-80 database from which the concrete data might have been taken/inspired etc.

Comment: Maybe. So far, you did not specify `borderscheck/3` and I am a bit skeptical: What if there is the very same `B` for different `Y`. You would count that length only once...

Answer (score 0):

```
?- aggregate_all(max(Area), (country(Country, _, Area, _),
\+ geo_sea(_, Country, _)), MaxArea),
country(Country, _, MaxArea, _).
Country = angola,
MaxArea = 1246700.
```

Comment: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof/3 will *not* help in finding the maximum area. To find the maximum, `aggregate_all` is a convenient one-liner.

Comment: ... I was wrong, as @false shows, since `setof` sorts. It's still far more sensible/efficient to just find a maximum, than to sort an entire list only to use the first value.

Comment: Ideally, yes, `aggregate_all` *could* be a better solution. At the moment, there are a few things to consider: (1) `aggregate_all` may or may not be faster than `setof/3`, that depends on the actual implementation. (2) `aggregate_all` may or may not be available on a particular Prolog system.  `setof/3` is offered by any ISO-Prolog system.